# Defensive measures for accessing arrays and dictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

What's the most effective way to defend against nil values in nested dictionaries and arrays?

I have an array that contains dictionaries, which contain arrays, which contain dictionaries, so I have a method that wants to return something like this:

```
return myArray[0][@"Categories"][0][@"Content"];
```

Currently I have the following, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, or more elegant way to defend these nested structures:

```
if (myArray) {
  // Add a check for myArray.count > 0
  if ([myArray[0] objectForKey:@"Categories"]) {
    // Add a check for myArray[@"Categories"].count > 0
    if ([myArray[0][@"Categories"][0] objectForKey:@"Content"]) {
      return myArray[0][@"Categories"][0][@"Content"];
    }
  } 
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Are there holes I haven't plugged?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:  I added comments for adding to check array counts.  With those additions is my access to to the object at myArray[0][@"Categories"][0][@"Content"] safe?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean Null instead of nil? For example, when parsing a JSON response, NSNull objects will often be inserted when you might be expecting an array or dictionary, and in these cases your code above would crash.

Comment: You meant `objectForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Yes, I meant NSNull, but more generally, how should I defend against accessing an object at:  myArray[0][@"Categories"][0][@"Content"] without producing a crash if there are NSNull values...  It looks like I do need to add two more if's to check array counts for out of bounds...

Comment: Accessing `someArray[0]` is *not* "safe" in all contexts, since `someArray` may have no elements at all.

Comment: Rather than repeating the `objectForKey:@"Categories"` call, I'd strongly suggest assigning the result to a temp before the second `if`, then using that temp for the 3rd `if` rather than re-executing the access.  In general it's better to split things apart with temps at each step, so that you can more readily insert checks after the fact and to make things easier to debug.  There is no significant efficiency gain from glomming everything together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither arrays or dictionaries can contain `nil`. So you're trying to protect against the requested key / index not existing.

If the dictionary key doesn't exist that's fine, you will just get `nil` back and any message to `nil` is 'ignored'.

The problem comes when you have an array and you try to ask for an index that's out of bounds. So what you should really be doing is checking the `count` of the arrays rather than checking the existence of keys.

Comment: So I only need to check the arrays for out of bounds and that's it?

Comment: Check the answer from @HotLicks as it covers the `NSNull` cases as well.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, neither an NSDictionary nor an NSArray can contain `nil` values.  However, they can contain the (singleton) value `NSNull`, and an NSDictionary will return `nil` from `objectForKey` if the key is not found.

In terms of "defensive" referencing, particularly with decoded JSON, you may need several checks.

First off, make sure you really do have the expected kind of object (some JSON providers may return an outer array on one access and an outer dictionary on the next) by using `isKindOfClass`:  `if ([iThinkItsADict isKindOfClass:(NSDictionary class)]) { ...`

Next, if accessing an array, make sure the index you are going to use is within the bounds of the array (keeping in mind that an array may have zero entries):  `if (arrayIndex < someArray.count) { ...`

When a value is returned from a dictionary, it may be `nil`, if the key was not found.  So you can test with `if (returnedValue != nil) {...`  (Though note that if a nil value is used to "dispatch" a method call the call will "succeed" without error but return zero/nil.  So it is not always necessary to check for nil.)

A dictionary or an array can return an NSNull, which you can check against with `if (returnedValue != [NSNull null]) {...`  (Some will object that you should not use `==` or `!=` to compare objects for equality, but there is only ever one `NSNull` object in the app.)

Answer (score 1):

Neither `NSArray`s nor `NSDictionary`s can have `nil` values. They throw an exception if you try to create them with one or insert one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough to use introspection, check if the objects that you get are arrays or dictionaries, remembering that nil targeted actions are ignored, and they return zero:

```
if([myArray isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]] && myArray.count)
{ // If myArray is nil isKindOfClass: and count will return 0
    if([myArray[0] isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
    {
        if([myArray[0][@"Categories"] isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]] && 
            [myArray[0][@"Categories"].count)
        {  // If it doesn't contain this key, objectForKey: returns nil 
           // and nil targeted actions are ignored.
            if([myArray[0][@"Categories"][0] isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary class]])
            {
                return myArray[0][@"Categories"][0][@"Content"];
                // If the key is not contained in the dictionary it will return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the category methods I use to defend against JSON parsing surprises where you don't get the array/dictionary that the spec would lead you to expect.

```
@implementation NSObject (TWXNSObject)

- (BOOL)exists
{
   if ([[NSNull null] isEqual:self])
      return NO;
   return YES;
}

// an empty JSON dictionary comes through as an array
- (BOOL)isDictionary
{
   if (!self.exists)
      return NO;
   if (![self isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
      return NO;
   return YES;
}

@end
```

A method to validate your array access would look like this:

```
- (BOOL)isIndexValid:(NSUInteger)idx
{
   if (!self.exists)
      return NO;
   if (![self isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
      return NO;
   if (idx >= self.count)
      return NO;
   return YES;
}
```

In theory, you could swizzle out the implementations of -objectForKeyedSubscript and -objectAtIndexedSubscript to add these checks transparently to the subscript syntax. In practice since NSDictionary and NSArray are class clusters it's foreseeable that will fail in surprising ways sooner or later. So you'd be better off defining something like

```
@implementation NSDictionary (TWXNSDictionary)

- (id)safeObjectForKey:(id)key
{
   if (self.isDictionary)
      return [self objectForKey:key];
   return nil;
}

@end

@implementation NSArray (TWXNSArray)

- (id)safeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
   if ([self isIndexValid:idx])
      return [self objectAtIndex:idx];
   return nil;
}

@end
```

and using those whenever you're accessing data structures that come from JSON parsing or other sources which may mismatch your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the good way is to swizzle `objectAtIndexedSubscript`

Like this [Objective-C Literals: Negative Array Subscripts](http://www.blendedcocoa.com/blog/2012/10/25/objective-c-literals-negative-array-subscripts/)

```
method_exchangeImplementations(
    class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:)),
    class_getInstanceMethod(self, @selector(BLC_objectAtIndexedSubscript:))
);

- (id)BLC_objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSInteger)idx {
    if (idx < 0) {
        idx = [self count] + idx;
    }

    return [self BLC_objectAtIndexedSubscript:idx];
}
```